# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Can't able to connect database in only laravel 7

my url is http://localhost:8000/index

Here is my project .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=amazon_services
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

i have run the following commands but still facing error

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

But i can able to connect the database in laravel 5.4 version while using url like this http://localhost/larave/laravel5.4/inde but while using laravel 7 with development server not connected

[image: Refer the image]

Comment: remove `""` from password in .env and just run php artisan config:clear

Comment: not working when remove "" in password in .env file

Comment: So your `root` is passwordless, amazing ..

Answer (score 0):

This probably is permission error by mySql.

If you are using root as username with no password please add user privileage to the database table you are connecting to like below.

[image]

Furthermore you will also need to grant access to root user to perform specific action on table.

[image]

And then

[image]

If the above solution did not work for you try following

> php artisan config:cache

> php artisan config:clear

> php artisan cache:clear

Keep your .env file as

```
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Then it probably is your php or mysql version. try upgrading to latest php version. Try using mariaDB instead of MySql

Comment: Else it is that you probably have set root password on localhost for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Open .env and change that :

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PASSWORD=
```

If the problem persists, try logging into mysql yourself.